# inverseJoinColumns annotation creating automatically UK in DB

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I mapped my entity as it follows:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "ETAPA_TAREFA", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ID_ETAPA", nullable = true) },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_TAREFA", nullable = true)})
private List<Tarefa> tarefas;
```

But when I run the app as spring boot app, it's generating automatically this UK:

```
   UNIQUE KEY `UK_8wxkehubnqsaiv0yip2m6v8ka` (`ID_TAREFA`),
```

But i don't want it. Tried to use nullable = true in order to avoid it but with no success.

Is there any annotation I can use or some properties in application.properties to supress this uk generation?

I'm using mysql as db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, the problem was One to Many.
The corret for what I want is @ManyToMany